# Need help p5.js and Atom Text Editor

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, p5.js

Well I recently started off with `atom` and `p5.js` well I am very new to `JavaScript`. Here comes my problem : When I try to run the file it shows me `"sketch.js is not a .py file, exit"` . I checked the the selection is set to `JavaScript` but can't figure out what is wrong.. Please Help !

Well the `"sketch.js"` is the default one which comes with `"p5.js"` and yes I have installed `"node.js"` so no issues with that and the problem comes when I edit the `"Sketch.js"` template and try to run it , it shows saving and after that it says `"sketch.js is not a .py file, exit"`

Comment: as it stand the question is confusing.  It sounds like you are you are running asa .js file and as a .py file.

Comment: I don't know Atom, but it probably only supports running Python natively. Try installing https://atom.io/packages/script or https://atom.io/packages/atom-runner package. Also you would need to install node.js in your system in order to run JavaScript.

Comment: Looks like some teething issues with your `Atom` editor, one thing which is really very strange is that your are mentioning that you are trying to run `sketch.js` but the `error` message is mentioning something about `.py` file not sure about this part. Can you also elaborate if you have installed any additional packages in your `Atom`. If you can please elaborate `sketch.js` too just in case.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to isolate your problem. Is the problem in the Atom editor, or is it with P5.js?

Try running your sketch as a standalone `.html` file that you create with a basic text editor (like JEdit or Notepad, not with Atom). Can you get that working by itself?

Then try running a more basic JavaScript application in Atom. Try simply printing something to the console. If you're still getting the error, then you know it has nothing to do with P5.js.

Isolating your problem like this will help you refine your Google searches, and it will make it easier for people to help you.

Note that P5.js does not require node.js, which runs on a server. It requires regular client-side JavaScript.

I'll also just note that if you're having trouble with stuff like this, it's a good idea to stick with a basic text editor and write and run your code by hand for a while. Code editors hide a lot from you, which can be nice, but not if you're still learning the fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely using an editor like Genie or something which runs python programs by default.  Have you installed node.js?  If not install it and then browse to the directory using command prompt.  Then run `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" file.js`